# How to create a silent installer package using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, visual-studio-setup-proje

I am using Visual Studio2008 for my development and i want to create a silent set up package i.e. i don't want any UI to come up during installation. Is it possible to create a silent installer MSI using Visual Studio and if not then are there any other tools to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MSI runs silently with the appropriate command line options, I don't think there is any way around that. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx) - you have to use the /q switch.

An alternative is [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 5):

An addition to what ocdecio said (which is absolutely correct):

If you want to make silent installation the default, i.e. the standard install action when a user double-clicks your setup file, you can wrap your MSI in a self-extracting executable file created by IExpress.

IExpress is included with Windows and allows you to specify a command to be executed after the IExpress-package has been extracted. In your case you would have to specify

```
msiexec /i mySetup.msi /q
```

as the installation command (in certain cases you would need /qn to absolutely suppress all dialogs).

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio's Solution Explorer, you have to remove the default Install Package User Interface.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IV8F.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgmvJ.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30523254)

Answer (score 0):

See "DETAILS ON SILENT INSTALL REQUIREMENT" here:
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-creating-your-msi-installer-using-visual-studio-2008